# Multithreading concepts

Tags: java

I am trying to understand a couple of Java concepts:

- How do I create a name for a thread when it includes a start and end value?
- How do I print out threads within a range? ie. Name_1_10, Name_11_20, etc.

Comment: Is your question about creating name strings or does it actually have something to do with threads?

Comment: It is to create a name string

Comment: You don't need to create a name for a thread, you may simply call `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to get the name of a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public String makeName(String prefix, int min, int max) {
    return prefix + "_" + min + "_" + max;
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
String firstName = makeName("Name", 1, 10);
// etc.
```